# How to configure CircleCI with ssh key for Ansible/SSH

Tags: github, ssh, ansible, circleci

I want to execute Ansible in my Circle CI pipeline. Something like this [example](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/orbss/ansible).

How do I configure my CircleCI Ansible orb to use my IP and private SSH key to login to my worker VM?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to, but you should be able to inject your SSH key in a secret. The IP will require a worker from your machine/IP space, which is a lot more work.

Answer (score 2):

That's how you do it

```
version: 2
jobs:
  deploy-job:
    steps:
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - "SO:ME:FIN:G:ER:PR:IN:T"
```

;) https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/add-ssh-key#adding-ssh-keys-to-a-job